# rejection region for correlated bivariate normal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, type-i-and-ii-errors, bounds, sequential-analysis

**STATEMENT OF PROBLEM:**

Suppose $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ Z_1 \\ Z_2  \end{array} \right)$ follows a Bivariate standard normal with covariance $ \rho $

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ Z_1 \\ Z_2  \end{array} \right) \sim MVN  \left( \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ 0 \\ 0  \end{array} \right) ,\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho  \\
\rho & 1  \\ \end{array} \right) \right) $

I am trying to solve for the rejection region **c** *as a function of* $\alpha$ such that:

$ P(|Z_1|\ge c) + P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2| \ge c  ) =\alpha $

**MY PAST ATTEMPTS:**

The solutions is easy when $\rho=0$, as
$$ P(|Z_1|\ge c) + P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2| \ge c  ) =\alpha $$
by symmetry of LEFT probability, and by independence of that on the right...
$$ =2*[1-\Phi(c)] + P(|Z_1|<c)*P(|Z_2| \ge c  ) =\alpha $$
$$ =2*[1-\Phi(c)] + 2*[1-\Phi(c)][\Phi(c)-\Phi(-c)] =\alpha $$
$$ 2*[1-\Phi(c)] + 2*[1-\Phi(c)][2*\Phi(c)-1] =\alpha $$
$$ 4*[1-\Phi(c)]*\Phi(c)=\alpha $$
$$ 4*[\Phi(c)-\Phi(c)^2]=\alpha $$
$$ -4\Phi(c)^2+4\Phi(c)-\alpha=0 $$
which is a quadratic function of $\Phi(c)$, yielding
$$ \Phi(c)= \frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha}}{2} $$
Giving the solution for c as a function of $\alpha$:
$$ \boxed{c = \Phi^{-1} \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha}}{2} \right)} $$

However, when $\rho \ne0$, I cannot find a closed form solution!  All i can find is 
$$ 2*[1-\Phi(c)]+2*\int_{-c}^{c}\Phi\left( \frac{-c+\rho z}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)\phi(z) dz =\alpha $$
and solve it numerically.  **This WORKS, but does not yield the desired closed form solution**

The one hint that I was given was to use $ U_1 =Z_1 + Z_2$  and $U_2 = Z_1 - Z_2 $.  I tried this, to no avail.  Can anyone help??

**NOTE**

This problem goes on to ask for a similar solution when

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ Z_1 \\ Z_2 \\Z_3  \end{array} \right) \sim MVN  \left( \left( \begin{array}{ccc} \ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{array} \right) ,\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \rho & \rho \\
\rho & 1 & \rho \\
\rho & \rho & 1 \\ \end{array} \right) \right) $

Solve for the rejection region **c** *as a function of* $\alpha$ such that:

$ P(|Z_1|\ge c) + P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2| \ge c  )+ P(|Z_1|<c , |Z_2|<c , |Z_3| \ge c  ) =\alpha $

Comment: I believe this cannot generally be put into a closed form.  One integration can be done, leaving the integral of a Gaussian times an Error Function: that's as far as one can get.  One approach is to study the properties of this function of $(c,\rho)$ sufficiently well that it's as good as any other transcendental function in formulas.

Comment: If you assume you know $\rho$, you can multiply $(Z_1, Z_2)$ by the inverse of the "square root" ($PP^t = \Sigma$) of the assumed covariance matrix $\Sigma$, thereby obtaining $(U_1, U_2)$, which under the null hypothesis are independent.  For the Normal distribution, "independent" is equivalent to "covariance = 0", so your test for the case $\rho = 0$ can then be applied.

Comment: In other words, given a vector $\mathbf{Z}$ of $d$ standard normal
r.vs with given correlation matrix, find $c>0$ such that the
probability $R(c)$ of the square $\{ \max_i |Z_i| \leq c \}$ has fixed
value $1- \alpha$. Even for $d=2$, I agree with @whuber saying that no
general tractable form will be found.  For small $d$ a
numerical solution can rely on the R package `mvtnorm` by A. Genz et
al. allowing a fast computation of $R(c)$ with a very good
precision. This can work with any correlation matrix: compound symmetry or any other specific form being unlikely to lead to a simpler problem.